# Limit libcurl response data

Tags: c, api, libcurl

i'm trying to get some number of bytes from source using libcurl by setting:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 100); //get 100 bytes from source
```

But I get different size of data each time, not even close sometimes only 22 bytes. does this work?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Pass a long specifying your preferred
>   size (in bytes) for the receive buffer
>   in libcurl. The main point of this
>   would be that the write callback gets
>   called more often and with smaller
>   chunks. This is just treated as a
>   request, not an order. You cannot be
>   guaranteed to actually get the given
>   size. (Added in 7.10)
>
> This size is by default set as big as
>   possible (CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE), so it
>   only makes sense to use this option if
>   you want it smaller.you want it smaller.

So there isn't really any easy way to get 100 bytes right away. You would need to keep track of how many bytes you have received and just stop reading once you've got 100.